# How can i get few characters from String?

Tags: android, string, substring

I want to retrieve few characters from string i.e., String data on the basis of first colon (:) used in string  . The String data possibilities are,

```
String data = "smsto:....."
String data = "MECARD:....."
String data = "geo:....."
String data = "tel:....."
String data = "MATMSG:....."
```

I want to make a generic String lets say,

```
String type = "characters up to first colon"
```

So i do not have to create String type for every possibility and i can call intents according to the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the scheme of a uri. You can use `Uri.parse(data).getScheme()`. This will return `smsto, MECARD, geo, tel` etc...

Check out the Developers site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme()

Answer (score 0):

Note: @Alessandro's method is probably more efficient. I just got that one off the top of my head.

You can use this to get characters up to first ':':

```
String[] parts = data.split(":");
String beforeColon = parts[0];
// do whatever with beforeColon
```

But I don't see what your purpose is, which would help giving you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `indexOf` - with that you can get the index of a certain `char`. Then you retrieve the substring starting from that index. For example:

```
int index = string.indexOf(':');
String substring = string.substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: Up to first colon!  So use the overloaded string.substring(0, index);